# how to gather element with index in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

index = tf.constant([[1],[1]])
values = tf.constant([[0.2, 0.8],[0.4, 0.6]])
```

if I use `extract = tf.gather_nd(values, index)`
the return is

```
[[0.4 0.6]
 [0.4 0.6]]
```

However, I want the result is

```
[[0.8], [0.6]]
```

where the index is along axis = 1, however, there is no axis parameter setting in tf.gather_nd.

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm a software engineer at Google and I'd like to quote this question in a research paper we're writing, to showcase some representative questions about TensorFlow. Would that be alright with you? Thanks, David

Comment: @DavidBieber Sure, thank you for asking :) Also thank you for building this amazing tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate a range to `index`:

```
index = tf.stack([tf.range(index.shape[0])[:, None], index], axis=2)
result = tf.gather_nd(values, index)
```

```
result.eval(session=tf.Session())
array([[0.8],
       [0.6]], dtype=float32)
```